# How to define a Kubernetes Service with Terraform and ClusterIP

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I can define a service just fine with NodePort or LoadBalancer, but when I try and use ClusterIP Terraform gives me this message

```
Failed to update service: Service "hello-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP'
```

It's an odd message because I'm not supplying a nodePort. Presumably it is defaulting to something ClusterIP doesn't want. This is my service definition:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "hello-service" {
  metadata {
    name = "hello-service"
    labels = {
      app = "hello"
    }
  }
  spec {
    type = "ClusterIP" 
    selector = {
      app = "hello"
    }
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 8080
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

  }
}
```

I've been over the docs and haven't seen anything that has to be different for ClusterIP. What did I miss?

```
terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.4
+ provider.google v3.3.0
+ provider.kubernetes v1.10.0

Running on GCP
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating the service from scratch or updating an existing one?

Comment: this sounds like bug in the provider implementation?

Comment: @Mafor creating  new service

Answer (score -2):

1. Please try using `$ kubectl apply -f your-service-conf-file.yaml   --force`
2. You can also execute `$ kubectl replace` command

   **Note:** it requires specifying the clusterIP field to be the same IP
   as the allocated ClusterIP of this service
3. You can use helm to fix the issue too:

   ```
       - port: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }} {{- if (eq .Values.service.type "ClusterIP") }}
         nodePort: null {{- end }}
         targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
         protocol: TCP
         name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
   ```

   This only works  *after*  the first install. So there's no
   "declarative" workaround, you need to change your service manually.
4. Finally workaround might be deleting the service first: `$ kubectl delete svc my-nginx`

   Then you can create service with poper type.

More information you can find here: [service-types-issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/221).

Comment: kubectl works fine. Probably Helm does too. The question is about Terraform.

Comment: Did you try deleted previously created service which was assigned to specific pod ?

Comment: Yes. Creating a new service w ClusterIP fails for me